# Stop a goroutine that writes to a channel indefinitely

Tags: go, deadlock, channel

I have a function that creates a goroutine that populates a channel indefinitely, e.g.,:

```
func Foo() <-chan int {
  ch := make(chan int) 
  go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    for {
      ch <- 1
    } 
  }() 
  return ch
}
```

And let's say we have a consumer that would like to stop after a while:

```
ch:=Foo() 
<-ch
<-ch
// done
```

Now I want to clean the goroutine resource including the channel. I tried to add a "done" channel for that but then I face a deadlock:

```
func Foo() (<-chan int, chan<- bool) {
  ch := make(chan int)
  done := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    for {
      select {
      case <-done:
          return
      default:
          ch <- 1
      }
    } 
  }() 
  return ch, done
}

func main() {
  ch, done := Foo()
  <-ch
  <-ch
  done <- true
  // HERE
}
```

Now, it seems to work, but it is only because the program exits, if I replace `// HERE` with some io operation (e.g.,: `http.Get("http://google.com")`), I face a deadlock (`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`).
I wonder if there is another way to clean up the spawned goroutine and channel created by the `Foo` function.

Comment: Do `case ch<-1:` instead of `default`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `default` with `case` inside the started goroutine:

```golang
func Foo() (<-chan int, chan<- bool) {
  ch := make(chan int)
  done := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
    defer close(ch)
    for {
      select {
      case <-done:
          return
      case ch <- 1:
      }
    } 
  }() 
  return ch, done
}
```

The original code with the `default` case deadlocks because of the following reasons:

- The started goroutines, which writes to `ch` channel, instantly goes to the `default` case when there are no other concurrently running goroutines, which write to `done` channel. Then the goroutines blocks at the `ch <- 1` line until other goroutines reads the value from `ch`.
- The main goroutine reads twice from `ch`. This results in two successful execution loops at the started goroutine. Then it tries writing to `done`. At this time the started goroutine may already check the `select` statement, fall into the `default` case and block at `ch <- 1` line. So the main goroutine also blocks indefinitely at the `done <- true` line. This results in deadlock.